# Future<T> not compatible with Class that extends Task<T> in Java Executor Service

Tags: java, concurrency, future, executorservice

My class `DownloadTask` extends `javafx.concurrent.Task<Boolean>`

After submitting my task to an `ExecutorService`, I try to assign the result to a variable of type `Future<Boolean>`. However, the IDE warns me that my instantiated object has a generic type `<capture<?>>` and I don't know why.

My class `DownloadTask`:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

private class DownloadTask extends Task<Boolean>{
    public DownloadTask() {}

    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
         return true;
    }
}
```

How I manage the thread pool:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
ArrayList<Future<Boolean>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

for (ScheduleRow scheduleRow : queArray) {
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    Future<Boolean> result = executor.submit(downloadTask); //incompatible types

    resultList.add(result);
}

executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: What is the `Task` class here?

Comment: Presumably the problem is that `Task<T> implements Runnable`, not `Callable<T>`, so it's returning a `Future<?>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Hi. I am not sure I understand. According to what I have read I can use a Task and call it by submitting it to the executor. I am new to this so I barely understand it.

Comment: But what is this "Task" class? I can't see such a class in [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Where is it declared?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html

Comment: @AndyTurner Example of a class extending Task here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/extendsTask.htm

Comment: You prrobably wanted Callable not Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

To resolve that warning, you *could* just add type info to enable type inference:

```
Future<Boolean> result = executor.submit(downloadTask, true);
```

However be aware, for the `result` variable, the `Future`'s `get` method will return the given *true* upon successful completion, since the `DownloadTask` is interpreted as a `Runnable` that doesn't produce a result. As Mike Strobel says, a better way is to get the correct result from the `DownloadTask` itself, as it also is a `Future<Boolean>`:

```
executor.submit(downloadTask);
resultList.add(downloadTask);
```

**Long answer**

As Andy Turner said, the inherited typye for `javafx.concurrent.Task` is `Runnable` (since it extends `FutureTask` implementing `RunnableFuture`).

Passing this to the `Future<?> submit(Runnable task)` method of the `ExecutorService` will yield a `Future<?>` result and the IDE will throw that nasty `Future<capture<?>>`.

However, you don't need a javafx-specific `ExecutorService`, the `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` works fine, since `DownloadTask` is a subclass of `FutureTask`.

To fix the type inference, you can use the generic `<T> Future<T> submit(Runnable task, T result)` method of the `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`. Since it's a simple Boolean you can rely on autoboxing:

```
Future<Boolean> result = executor.submit(downloadTask, true);
```

The problem is that, for the `result` variable, the `Future`'s get method will return the given *true* upon successful completion. In your example, the `get` method on the resulting `Future` would always return `null`. That is because it is interpreted as a `Runnable` that doesn't produce a result. As Mike Strobel says, a better way is to get the correct result from the DownloadTask itself, as it also is a Future:

```
executor.submit(downloadTask);
resultList.add(downloadTask);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of [`javafx.concurrent.Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), `Task` implements `Runnable`, not `Callable<T>`.

As such, when you submit it to an `ExecutorService`, it is treated like something which does not return a value, so the resulting future is a `Future<?>`.

Either use a javafx-specific `ExecutorService` (no idea if there is one specially for `Task`); or have your class implement `Callable<Boolean>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything with the result of `submit`; your `DownloadTask` is *already* a `Future<Boolean>`, and when it runs, it will set its own result.  The `Future<?>` returned by `submit` is not capable of forwarding the result of your task anyway, as it simply sees it as a `Runnable` that does not produce a value.

Simply change this:

```
Future<Boolean> result = executor.submit(downloadTask);
resultList.add(result);
```

To this:

```
executor.submit(downloadTask);
resultList.add(downloadTask);
```